# Laravel Mail: How can I sent a mail automatically to a user as a message after 1 month of time in laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, cron-task

I want to sent mail or notification to user in their gmail account automatically after 1 month. Any suggestion on how to do it in laravel.

For example : when user register a current date then the notification must be sent after 1 month automatically when the time reaches.

I am kind of confused and little suggestion will be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Laravel cronjobs for [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling), Following tutorial will help you with cron-jobs:

**[How to set up Cron job in Laravel](https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel)**

Comment: if it helps you, feel free to mark the answer as correct... :P

Answer (score 1):

First you should write a [laravel command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) or any function that handles the task you want to run periodically then add the command to [task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)
and in the end add make the laravel task scheduling work by adding

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

to the cronjobs of linux. You can also edit the cron jobs of linux by

```
crontabs -e
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should write a laravel command or any function that handles the
task you want to run periodically

Inside file `App\Console\Commands\COMMAND_NAME` write your code inside handle
function

```
 protected $signature = 'command_call';  # Like 'report:send'
 
 public function handle()
    {
    ......
    ....
    }
```

then add the command to task scheduler
and in the end add make the laravel task scheduling work by adding

Inside file `App\Console\Kernel` define your command name with path

```
 protected $commands = ['App\Console\Commands\COMMAND_NAME']
```

then, Inside schedule function

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('report:send')->monthly();
        //for send the user report Every month
    }
```

Then in your cron job :-

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```